Giving application window active focus when opening a file
In the documentation for QWidget::activateWindow() function, the following is said:

... On Windows, if you are calling this when the application is not
currently the active one then it will not make it the active window.
It will change the color of the taskbar entry to indicate that the
window has changed in some way. This is because Microsoft does not
allow an application to interrupt what the user is currently doing in
another application...

This is a problem seeing as how it makes perfect sense when the user double clicks on a file, to open that file in a currently running instance of the application and bring the main application window into active focus. Photoshop does this, for example. When you double click on a Photoshop project file from within Windows Explorer, if Photoshop is already open, it brings the Photoshop application window to the front and displays the opened project. How can I do this within Qt? I have tried this:
window->raise()
window->requestActivate()

which does nothing when opening a file from Windows Explorer. Then I tried the Windows API stuff:
if (IsIconic(hwnd))
{
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_RESTORE); // Restore the window if it is minimized
}
SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
SetFocus(hwnd);
SetActiveWindow(hwnd);

which also does nothing when opening a file from Windows Explorer. Is there a way to do this?

Not active window can't receive focus.

If you're on Qt5, did you check the setWindowActivationBehavior() function of QWindowsWindowFunctions class? Also check this forum post

@musicamante It worked! Thanks. I'm actually a musician too :-)

This question is similar to: Force keyboard focus to LineEdit QT. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@comp1201 That's good, you're welcome. Consider either accepting the duplicate proposal, or eventually answer your own question by clicking the related button with a basic MRE that shows how you did it and possibly noting the Qt6 unavailability (by linking the post above).
